# Что делать если некоторые устройства не поддерживаются сайтом?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Все уже привыкли, что сайт поддерживает все разрешения экранов, от больших до маленьких, но что делать, если у меня приложение, которым будет удобно пользоваться только до разрешения в 1024px? Не оставить же просто так, чтобы пользователи заходили и видели скролл, нужна заглушка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте в `<head>` строчку:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Подробнее об этом можно почитать, например, [тут](http://html5.by/blog/viewport-meta-tag/).

Единственная проблема может быть только в том, что на небольших мобильных устройствах контент будет мелким и плохо читаемым.

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему, надо делать сайты пригодные для любых разрешений экранов. Вы можете использовать `media-queries` чтобы переопределить ваши css-стили для разных разрешений экрана.

Если же вы хотите блокировать пользователей, которые зашли с экранов высокого разрешения, то можете при загрузке страницы проверять через JavaScript ширину экрана и если она больше 1024px, то выводить вместо контента предупреждение, что сайт предназначен только для мобильных устройств.